# Why is this try loop looping when I changed it not to?

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

I am absolutely new to coding and wanted to make a guessing game for a start. that's why the code probably looks extremely scuffed if you know what you're doing. I don't. I want the code to loop if it gets an answer that is not y/n, but the issue is that now even if it recieves a yes/no answer, it still loops and keeps asking the same question.

```
while not infiniteguessanswer:
    try:
        if numberofchances > 50:
            infiniteguess = input('it seems the number you put it is very high! would you just like infinite guesses instead? Y/N\n')
            if infiniteguess == ['Y', 'y', 'yes', 'yea', 'Yeah', 'Yes'] :
                infiniteguessanswer=True
                numberofchances = math.inf
            elif infiniteguess == ['N', 'n', 'no', 'No'] :
                infiniteguessanswer=True
            if infiniteguess != 'y' and infiniteguess != 'n':
                print('WHY DOES THIS LOOP INFINITELY?????')     
        
        
        if numberofchances < 50:
            print ('alright!')
            infiniteguessanswer=True
    
    except:
        print('ok')
```

Comment: `infiniteguess == ['Y', 'y', 'yes', 'yea', 'Yeah', 'Yes']` should be `infiniteguess in ['Y', 'y', 'yes', 'yea', 'Yeah', 'Yes']`

Answer (score 0):

The user input **can't** be equal to the **whole** list, you need to check for inclusion

```
infiniteguess in ['Y', 'y', 'yes', 'yea', 'Yeah', 'Yes']

infiniteguess in ['N', 'n', 'no', 'No']
```

Answer (score -1):

The while loop is checking for any  value but not specific to to a type of value, that's why it loops irrespective of the value; so instead of:  while not infiniteguessanswer use
While infiniteguessanswer is True or False: then do the loop OR use membership testing to check if a value is an accepted value just as used here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm. i have just edited your code in the sample below:

```
While infiniteguessanswer in ['Y', 'y', 'yes', 'yea', 'Yeah', 'Yes', 'N', 'n', 'no', 'No']:
try:
    if numberofchances > 50:
        infiniteguess = input('it seems the number you put it is very high! would you just like infinite guesses instead? Y/N\n')
        if infiniteguess in ['Y', 'y', 'yes', 'yea', 'Yeah', 'Yes'] :
            infiniteguessanswer = True
            numberofchances = math.inf
        elif infiniteguess in ['N', 'n', 'no', 'No'] :
            infiniteguessanswer=True
        if infiniteguess != 'y' and infiniteguess != 'n':
            print('WHY DOES THIS LOOP INFINITELY?????')     
    
    
    if numberofchances < 50:
        print ('alright!')
        infiniteguessanswer=True

except:
    print('ok')
```

before the loop starts you have to ask for a value for infiniteguessanswer. maybe something like this: `infiniteguessanswer = input('Do you want to play infinite guess loop?')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).